# Artificial non Kosher food

Tags: halacha, food, kashrut-kosher, technology, taste

According to Vayikra we have:

> ז  וְאֶת-הַחֲזִיר כִּי-מַפְרִיס פַּרְסָה הוּא, וְשֹׁסַע שֶׁסַע פַּרְסָה, וְהוּא, גֵּרָה לֹא-יִגָּר; טָמֵא הוּא, לָכֶם.‏
>
> 7 And the swine, because he parteth the hoof, and is cloven-footed, but cheweth not the cud, he is unclean unto you.

Nowadays it's possible to mimetize flavours and aromas. Artificial Flavors are flavors that have been created for food that do not exist in nature or simply an attempt to clone a flavor found in nature.
Most artificial flavors are specific and often complex mixtures of singular naturally occurring flavor compounds combined together to either imitate or enhance a natural flavor.
Many flavorants consists of esters. They are creadted in laboratories.

The question is: Is it any wrong to have food with artificial flavours of non kosher foods?such as food with bacon flavour?(because it is not the bacon itself)

If not, why?

Comment: I've seen bacon bits, fake lobster, and similar items with credible hechshers, so it appears to be ok.  The prohibition is against, e.g., *pig*, not *pig flavor*.  Are you looking for sources for that?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes, I would like to know if *even* the flavour, being artificial or not, do not supposesd to be consumed.

Comment: @onicaCellio On the other hand, transferring taste from pork to beef makes the beef prohibited.

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18378 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14436

Comment: @DoubleAA if it actually originated from a pig then it's a problem.  If it's completely synthetic, well apparently OU thinks fake "bacon bits" are ok.  msh210, good find -- I *thought* we'd seen something like this before but I didn't find it.

Comment: Regardless, I wouldn't advise eating them for maris ayin reasons.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Gemarah in Chullin 109 writes for everything that is prohibited there is a thing which is kosher and is the same.The gemara brings the שיבוטא which is a kosher fish head which tastes like pig.So from this gemara it is permitted,l.The Chida also permits this based on this gemara.

Comment: To read the Chida read here in ספר פתח עינים חולין דף קט http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40655&st=&pgnum=257&hilite=

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbus_grypus http://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2Fs10641-006-6698-7.pdf