# Alopecia and maris haayin

Tags: halacha, marit-ayin, payot-sideburns

Some cases of [Alopecia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alopecia_areata) result in the loss of **all** the hair on one's head.

Would such a person cause *maris haayin* that they violated the prohibition of rounding the corner of their head? Would they have to wear a wig? Or is their condition obvious such that no one would suspect them of transgression. Do the *poskim* discuss this?

Comment: Relevant rationale and sources for an answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92460/15571).

Comment: I'm not sure you can violate "maris ayin" passively. It's not his fault he doesn't have hair

Comment: There is a discussion in the Gemara (in nazir? Maybe makos?) If the prohibition applies in the first place to someone who shaves his whole head.

Comment: @DoubleAA you made me think of an analogous case: someone forced to get a tattoo, I recall they don't have to remove it. Obviously someone from a concentration camp everyone knows why they have a tattoo. But a young Frum man with a tattoo, even if they don't have to remove it, maybe they should inform others that they were compelled?

Comment: @robev https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12421/759

Comment: @robev I have met people who had tattoos from before they did teshuvah (so they were not compelled). After they became a baal teshuvah, they were told not to remove it as the method of removal, is also a tattoo (though they do keep it covered). There are also people who had a tattoo put on for medical reasons (such as to mark a spot as a target for radiation therapy). They were also told not to have it removed, though nowadays, one can have a temporary marking used so it will wear off after the therapy is complete.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *Maase Rav*.

R. Lior Glazer is a famous speaker, giving many lectures to large audiences, suffering from a health condition that causes him a complete loss of hair.

He doesn't care about Marit Ayin, nor do other Rabbis protest.

[image: One picture is better then thousand words]