# Can a genetically modified pig be kosher, if gestated in a kosher animal?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, technology, animals, medicine

[This answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/if-a-pig-was-genetically-modified-to-chew-its-cud-would-it-be-kosher#) says that a pig that was genetically modified to chew it's cud would not be kosher if gestated in a pig. For clarification, would it be kosher if it was gestated in a cow or other kosher animal?

Comment: Is this a dupe of the linked question?

Comment: that answer does not specify if the animal WOULD e kosher if it was gestated in a kosher animal it only says its not kosher if its not

Comment: I didn’t ask if it’s a dupe of the linked answer, but rather the question it was answering.

Comment: I'm specifying that it was gestated in a kosher animal

Comment: See [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3507/) for the community policy about duplicates of a broader question. The actual answers aside, is there any reason to think that a complete answer to a question which asks about GMO treif animals gestated in other animals wouldn’t address your question here?