# Is a genetically modified pig organ in

Tags: kashrut-kosher, non-kosher-species

If you are unaware, doctors recently performed a [surgery](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/pig-kidneys-transplanted-to-human-in-milestone-experiment/?amp=true) in which they added a genetically modified pig kidney into a living person.

I was curious, does this violate laws on kosher? Would it be allowed in Orthodox Judaism?

---

Related: [If a pig was genetically modified to chew its cud, would it be kosher?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2668/if-a-pig-was-genetically-modified-to-chew-its-cud-would-it-be-kosher)

Comment: Welcome @LukeHill. The title of your question is a little unclear (to me). Consider editing

Comment: @JoelK that’s my bad, I must have spaced out typing :)